# How to use/apply class inheritance in Enchant.js

Tags: javascript, inheritance, enchant.js

You're developing a game using Enchant.js and you just need an Enemy class which multiple enemy classes derive from and every enemy has its own sprite and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This old Enchant.js blog entry](http://blog.enchantjs.com/en/2012/01/18/enchant-js-succession-and-javascript-inheritance-the-subtle-differences/) talks about class inheritance and offers the following example

```
enchant();。

A = Class.create({
    initialize:function(){
        this.x=1;
    },
    method:function(){
        document.write(this.x);
    }
});

B = Class.create(A,{   //Inherits A
    initialize:function(){
    A.call(this);  // Calls up A constructor
        this.y=100;
    },
    anotherMethod:function(){
        document.write(this.x*this.y);
    }
});

var b = new B();
b.method();
b.anotherMethod();
```

So, using a Chess game example, in which you gotta pass parameters to the constructor in order to "build" the piece, what has worked for me is following those guidelines and taking advantage of the Sprite class like this:

```
var Piece = enchant.Class.create(enchant.Sprite, {
    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @param   object (game object reference)
     * @param   point (JSON object)
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */
    initialize: function(gameObj, position, color, type) {
        enchant.Sprite.call(this,g_SizeCell, g_SizeCell); // grid's cell size (global)
        this.image = gameObj.assets[g_ImgPieces]; // sprite sheet path (global)
        this.x = position.x;
        this.y = positino.y;
        // sprite sheet's frame selection
        switch (this.m_Type) {
            case "pawn":
            default:
                this.frame = 0;
                break;
            case "knight":
                this.frame = 1;
                break;
            case "bishop":
                this.frame = 2;
                break;
            case "rook":
                this.frame = 3;
                break;
            case "queen":
                this.frame = 4;
                break;
            case "king":
                this.frame = 5;
                break;
        }
        if (this.m_Color == "black") {
            this.frame += 6;
        }
    }
    // ... some other member functions
});

var Pawn = enchant.Class.create(Piece, {
    initialize: function(gameObj, position, color) {
        // this is the most important part
        // look that the current object is not in the parent's class signature
        Piece.call(this, gameObj, position, color, "pawn");
    }
    // ... some other member functions
});

// pawn creation for using in chessboard
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    point = {x:i,y:1};
    newpiece = new Pawn(gameObj, point, "black");
    scene.addChild(newpiece);
    point. y = 6;
    newpiece = new Pawn(gameObj, point, "white");
    scene.addChild(newpiece);
}
```